# Formatting nullable DateTime fields in strong typed View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, defaultmodelbinder

I have a Person class with a BornDate property in my model defined as

```
[DisplayName("Born Date")]
public DateTime? BornDate { get; set; }
```

I use this field in my view as

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.BornDate)%>
    <br />
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BornDate, new { id = "bornDate" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BornDate, "*")%>
</td>
```

The problem is that when I am editing a Person instance with the BornDate text box is formatted as

```
dd/MM/yyyy hh.mm.ss
```

while I would like to format it without the time part ("dd/MM/yyyy"). I am not able to use the toString method with the format string because it is a nullable field.

what can I do?

Comment: Good example also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633471

Comment: Good example about same problem can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633471

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use Value. Just check it isn't null first.

```
var displayDate = model.BornDate.HasValue ? model.BornDate.Value.ToString("yyyy") : "NoDate";
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. Where do I have to put this code? If I put it inside the TextBoxFor function, within the lambda expression, I get an InvalidOperationException "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: Hrm... yeah I forgot the fact you are using strongly typed helpers. I think the only way round this is to use the TextBox helper: <%= Html.TextBox("date", Model.BornDate.Value.ToString("yyyy"), new { id = "bornDate" }) %>

Comment: if anyone has issue to display date in View check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29742649/2218697) instead of `DisplayFor`

Answer (score 8):

I know this is very late but I was researching another problem and came across this issue. There is a way to only show the date part which does not require presentation layer formatting.

```
[DisplayName("Born Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? BornDate { get; set; }
```

Using this will ensure that everywhere you bind to this property on your View, only the date will show

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Doesn't work in current versions of Razor (4+); can't speak to older ones.

Comment: this doesn't work on all Html helpers, specifically TextBoxFor

Answer (score 6):

To do this in your VIEW, you can use Razor syntax, as well:

```
 @Html.TextBox("BornDate", item.BornDate.HasValue ? item.BornDate.Value.ToShortDateString():"")
```

Comment: How should I use for DisplayFor?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, it will work with Nullable model types:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    object txtVal = "";
    if (Model.HasValue) 
    {
        txtVal = Model.Value;
    };
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model, new {Value = string.Format(ViewData.ModelMetadata.EditFormatString, txtVal))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I've tackled this issue is by adding format to the TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BornDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { id = "bornDate" })
```