# MVC4 DataType.Date EditorFor won't display date value in Chrome, fine in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I'm using the DataType.Date attribute on my model and an EditorFor in my view. This is working fine in [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9), but in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) it is showing a date picker and instead of displaying the value it just displays "Month/Day/Year" in faded gray text.

Why won't Google Chrome display the value?

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EstPurchaseDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<td class="fieldLabel">Est. Pur. Date</td>
<td class="field">@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.EstPurchaseDate)</td>
```

[image: Chrome]

[image: Internet Explorer]

Answer (score 393, accepted):

When you decorate a model property with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` the default template in ASP.NET MVC 4 generates an input field of `type="date"`:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-date="The field EstPurchaseDate must be a date."
       id="EstPurchaseDate" 
       name="EstPurchaseDate" 
       type="date" value="9/28/2012" />
```

Browsers that support HTML5 such Google Chrome render this input field with a date picker.

In order to correctly display the date, the value must be formatted as `2012-09-28`. Quote from the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html):

> **value:** A valid full-date as defined in [RFC 3339], with the additional
>   qualification that the year component is four or more digits
>   representing a number greater than 0.

You could enforce this format using the `DisplayFormat` attribute:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EstPurchaseDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Darin thank you, that was perfect!  You've answered so many of my MVC questions over the past two years, you rock!

Comment: Great answer but I feel this is appealing you have to force it just to get the control to work properly!

Comment: What would be the way of doing this "globally" for all properties marked `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` so I wouldn't have to mark all these properties separately with the risk of missing some?

Comment: Darin, What can us people outside USA do? How can I set the specification value but display a custom date format? ie, UK?

Comment: @ppumkin: This is not US specific. In fact, the reason the HTML5 specification uses `YYYY-MM-DD` is because it's an international standard (ISO 8601). If you need to display the date in a different format, you'll need to utilize view models in your views so that you can set the date format for your form to ISO 8601, but set the date format for something like a detail view to whatever the localized version you desire is.

Comment: The format displayed in Chrome is whatever is set in your systems globalization settings. So, yes, set everything as per example in ISO 8601 but make sure the system is set to the correct Globale. After chaining it make sure to restart Chrome, Firefox.. not sure about IE or other browsers.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - I've hooked into the Model Metadata and I add this to the DisplayFormatString and to the EditFormatString.

Comment: @SwampyFox: Thanks! (Any references on how to do this?)

Comment: @MarjanVenema- I've used the "ExtensibleModelMetadataProvider" from Matt Honeycutt's FailTracker (https://github.com/MattHoneycutt/Fail-Tracker). Look under the Infrastructure Folder to the ModelMetadata. I've used those classes and then created an filter implementation of IModelMetadataFilter. When the TransformMetadata method is called, you can then edit the "DisplayFormatString" and "EditFormatString" properties of the metadata. Hope this gets you in the right direction (btw, there is a great pluralsight video that uses Fail-Tracker)

Comment: Its not working for me. Year part in date picker accepting upto 6 digits. How can i restrict to 4 digits. Heres my code : [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date in the format MM/DD/YYYY")]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth:")]
        [Required]
        public string DOB { get; set; }

Comment: Maaann, i was searching for this and I finally got it! thank you!!

Comment: Great answer! I had the same problem with 0:MM/dd/yyyy instead of the other way around - 0:yyyy-MM-dd. This worked (the commented-out annotations is what I originally had in my model:`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
  //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Answer (score 45):

In MVC5.2, add Date.cshtml to folder ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes;
    object objAttributes;
    if (ViewData.TryGetValue("htmlAttributes", out objAttributes))
    {
        htmlAttributes = objAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(objAttributes);
    }
    else
    {
        htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }
    htmlAttributes.Add("type", "date");
    String format = (Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome")) ? "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" : "{0:d}";
    @Html.TextBox("", Model, format, htmlAttributes)
}
```

Comment: thanks! fixes the mentioned chrome "issue" and of course you can have another displayformat on your datetime property!

Comment: Yes great solution. This provides an excellent work around for those of us not in the US.

Comment: I think this is the best solution to the problem, it fixes just the editor issue and doesn't affect existing display formatting.

Comment: Using "Date.cshtml" instead of "DateTime.cshtml" was the magic answer! It works in MVC 4 as well.

Comment: Great! Obrigado.

Comment: Had to stick with `DateTime.cshtml` instead of the recommended `Date`, but after a couple tweaks it worked great! One of my key changes was using the pre-formatted value (generated using the model property's specified DisplayFormat), which made the last line: `@Html.TextBox(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAttributes)`

Answer (score 19):

As an addition to Darin Dimitrov's answer:

If you only want this particular line to use a certain (different from standard) format, you can use in MVC5:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property, new {htmlAttributes = new {@Value = @Model.Property.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), @class = "customclass" } })
```

Comment: As there is `@` at the beginning, that `@Value = @Model.Property...` still need that `@`? Do you mean just `new { Value = Model.Property...`?

Comment: Can confirm, @user3454439

Answer (score 11):

In MVC 3 I had to add:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

among usings when adding properties:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Especially if you are adding these properties in .edmx file like me. I found that by default .edmx files don't have this using so adding only propeties is not enough.

Answer (score 10):

If you remove `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` from your model, the input field in Chrome is rendered as `type="datetime"` and won't show the datepicker either.

Comment: Thanks Bernie.  I wasn't so trouble with the picker showing up as I was with the data not being put into the input box.  This is good to know though.

Comment: Opera renders a datepicker though. Use modernizr to do some polyfill

Comment: If it's supposed to be a date, it should be rendered as an input of type `date`. Using `datetime` as a work-around is inappropriate, since it doesn't semantically represent the data.

Answer (score 4):

I still had an issue with it passing the format yyyy-MM-dd, but I got around it by changing the Date.cshtml:

```
@model DateTime?

@{
    string date = string.Empty;
    if (Model != null)
    {
        date = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", Model.Value.Year, Model.Value.Month, Model.Value.Day);
    }

    @Html.TextBox(string.Empty, date, new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
}
```

Comment: thank you finally this worked, i tried `string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}")` to get `dd/mm/yyyy` format, and it works fine,   i used database first method but  DisplayFormat didn't worked with partial class, don't know why?, anyway anyone  if needed try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1670255.aspx?EditorFor+DateTime+field+how+to+add+format) method , i didn't try but if anyone needed , hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Reply to **MVC4 DataType.Date EditorFor won't display date value in Chrome, fine in IE**

In the Model you need to have following type of declaration:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DateXYZ { get; set; }
```

OR

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateXYZ { get; set; }
```

You don't need to use following attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

**At the Date.cshtml use this template:**

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@using System.Globalization;

@{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    if (Model != null)
    {
        dt = (System.DateTime)Model;

    }

    if (Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE") || Request.Browser.Type.Contains("InternetExplorer"))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", dt.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
    }
    else
    {
        //Tested in chrome
        DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat;
        dtfi.DateSeparator = "-";
        dtfi.ShortDatePattern = @"yyyy/MM/dd"; 
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", dt.ToString("d", dtfi)), new { @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
    } 
}
```

Have fun!
Regards,
Blerton

Comment: If you do it this way, Chrome won't give you a date picker. I'm using your solution, but modifying so that 1) I DO use the `DisplayFormat` attribute 2) Change the test to check if the browser type is chrome, then do `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.EstPurchaseDate)` 3) Else do `@Html.TextBox("EstPurchaseDate", dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))` Note: on #2, a better check would be if the browser understands HTML5, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Downvoting for browser detection in server side code.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have control over the format of the date (in other words not just the yyyy-mm-dd format is acceptable), another solution could be adding a helper property that is of type string and add a date validator to that property, and bind to this property on UI.

```
    [Display(Name = "Due date")]
    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    [DateValidation]
    public string DueDateString { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DueDate 
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(DueDateString) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(DueDateString);
        }
        set
        {
            DueDateString = value == null ? null : value.Value.ToString("d");
        }
    }
```

And here is a date validator:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class DateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DateValidationAttribute()
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            DateTime date;

            if (value is string)
            {
                if (!DateTime.TryParse((string)value, out date))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(validationContext.DisplayName + " must be a valid date.");
                }
            }
            else
                date = (DateTime)value;

            if (date < new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) || date > new DateTime(3000, 12, 31))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(validationContext.DisplayName + " must be a valid date.");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```