# JQuery Mobile Date picker not showing date in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 site using JQuery Mobile.  I'm using a model with an EditorFor to render the date editor.  in MVC I have this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ActionDate)
```

The model property is defined as:

```
<Required>
<RegularExpression("\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}", ErrorMessage:="Please enter a date in the format of MM/DD/YY")>
<DataType(DataType.Date)>
<DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="MM/dd/yyyy")>
<Display(Name:="Action Date")>
Public Property ActionDate As Date
```

It renders HTML with the value of:

```
<input type="date" ... value="04/24/2013" />
```

But what shows to the user is this:

[image: Date Picker with Date not Showing]

The date isn't visible to the user, and the 4/24/2013 is not the default of Chrome's date picker.  How do I get chrome to actually show the date?

Thanks.

Comment: Chrome is doing all sorts of "intelligent" editing for date fields *that are driving us nuts*. My solution (below) was to simply change the field type from `date` to `text` on load.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html), the value passed to an `<input type="date">` element should be in [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) format.  This is a specific profile of [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601).

In other words, you need to pass the value in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit this exact same problem.

My solution was to avoid the `type="date"` problem by changing the type to text when I connect the datepicker:

```
$('#Date').removeAttr('type').attr('type', 'text').datepicker();
```

*If you are not using JQueryUI, just drop the datePicker part.*

As I also needed to force the default date format (again thanks to Chrome) it was:

```
$('#Date').removeAttr('type').attr('type', 'text').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Chrome is now biting us regularly with jQueryUI issues and has gone from being our favourite dev browser to our most troublesome (for compatibility issues).

Comment: Thanks, this perfectly helped me. I'm still confused why the solution of Darin Dimitrov doesn't work for me. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633471/mvc4-datatype-date-editorfor-wont-display-date-value-in-chrome-fine-in-ie

Comment: @jomsk1e: Seems to be an issue with Chrome and jQueryUI datepicker, more than any MVC issue. Still looking for a *correct* solution, but this avoids Chrome being too clever (for now).