# mvc 5 EditorFor format not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, editorfor, displayformat

I have researched this issue extensively and still can't find an answer.  I have a model with this date field:

```
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}", NullDisplayText = "")]
[Required]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ConsumptionDate;
```

I have a view with this EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConsumptionDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConsumptionDate, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

But the date still never gets formatted.  I have tried with and without "{0:d}" as the format in the EditorFor, and I have tried with and without [DataType(DataType.Date)] annotated on the model field.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  The binding works fine and I can save the data fine too - I just can't get it to format properly.

TIA
-VG

Comment: try this format, this is what I use: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Comment: I have tried "MM-dd-yyyy" format as well, but the format never gets applied regardless of which date format string I am trying.

Comment: the one you just mentioned is different from the one i posted, you should post all the formats you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't want the year to display first so I wouldn't use the format you posted.  I only tried the one other format.  "d" is what I really need tho, since that will take culture into consideration when formatting.

Comment: since you're using an `EditorFor()` with a `DateTime`, the rendered output  should be `<input type="date">`, which would make the *browser* responsible for figuring out how to display that. for instance, Chrome has a date editor control. In order for the input to recognize the string as a date, you will need to format it how I suggested. If you want to choose how the date is displayed, you should use `TextBoxFor()` instead of `EditorFor()`

Comment: I can get it to work with TextboxFor, yes, but all the advice on MVC indicates I _should_ be using EditorFor and indicating that all you need on an EditorFor is the DisplayFormat attribute on the model field.  So my question is, why is EditorFor not working?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by "In order for the input to recognize the string as a date, you will need to format it how I suggested".  How will formatting it with the year first help in any way?  Especially since that's not the format I need?

Comment: because you're not formatting properly, try formatting it like i said, you should get a value in. like i said, this will render as an `<input type="date">` which expects a certain string format in order to parse the string into a date properly, which is the one i specified. also, try adding `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Comment: Fine, I just tried your format as well.  Still didn't work.  In my original post I point out that I've already tried  [DataType(DataType.Date)]

Comment: Have you tried to remove "datePickerField" class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12634470/526704

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC4 DataType.Date EditorFor won't display date value in Chrome, fine in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633471/mvc4-datatype-date-editorfor-wont-display-date-value-in-chrome-fine-in-interne)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this has nothing to do with Chrome, and the display is fine, it just won't format.  You are starting to get off-topic.

Comment: If I remove the datePickerField class the datepicker stops working AND the date is still not formatted properly.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "format" for editorFor so of course "{0:d}" does nothing. If you want a format applied then use `Html.TextboxFor(...)`.

Comment: Hi @Shoe, I do see that EditorFor doesn't take a format field - that was a desperation move.  But the documentation indicates the data attribute on the model should be used and it's not formatting it either.

Comment: Are you using a jquery datepicker plugin or are you wanting to display the HTML5 datepicker implementation of the browser?

Comment: The datepicker is not important at this time.  I've removed that code from the above post to prevent distraction.  The problem occurs regardless of whether the field uses a datepicker or not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use System.DateTime with or without the questionmark (indicating that the editor can accept nullable datetimes?

```
@model System.DateTime?
```