# How to change date in editor in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have in model DateTime

```
public System.DateTime date_in { get; set; }
```

And this is its View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date_in, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date_in, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date_in, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

when I just click the `EditorFor()` to change the date, It writes:

> The field date_in must be a date.

all formats I tried to insert (with time and without and change the places of month and day) were wrong.

The individual way I 
succeeded is when month value and day value smaller than 13
I have tried answers people answered on similar questions
like add globalization tag and custom binder
but nothing helped me.

Comment: Did you try `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12634470/5112433

Comment: I tried now. your suggesion seems can help for Create but not for Edit, because it didn't shows me any date

Comment: What is the culture on your server?

Comment: no defined culture in <web.service>

Comment: The `1/30/2016` will work fine but `30/1/2016` will not. And using `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` is only supported in Chrome and Edge and if you use it you must also use `[DisplayFormat(DateFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyInEditModel = true)]`

Comment: sorry, does not work

Comment: Set the culture in you web config file to `en:US` and it will work fine! And if it not working for you then you have other errors in your code that you have not shown us.