# ASP.NET MVC 5 Date won't be shown in Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

ASP.NET MVC 5 Date won't be shown in Chrome.

There is no any culture settings in app.

How to fix it?

**Html**

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Changed,
                           new
                           { htmlAttributes =
                                    new { @class = "form-control", @Value = Model.Changed.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") } })
```

**Model**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime Changed { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC4 DataType.Date EditorFor won't display date value in Chrome, fine in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633471/mvc4-datatype-date-editorfor-wont-display-date-value-in-chrome-fine-in-interne)

Comment: @J.Swietek No no no It does not work, man

Comment: Did you try to remove the DataType attribute as said in the linked answer?

Comment: @J.Swietek If I remove it I lost the Chrome CALENDAR, But I need it.

Comment: What's this 'aaaa' in your editor? Did you change the output manually ? What's the real output? Try with [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" ...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In browsers that support the HTML5 `date`, `time`, and `datetime` input types, the value supplied *must* be in ISO format, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD` for `date`, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for `datetime`, etc. If it's not in that format, the browser cannot parse the value and therefore treats the input as if it has no value. So all you need is to change your `DisplayFormat` attribute to:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: Note also OP needs to remove `new { @Value = Model.Changed.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") }`