# Date in Editing in MVC5 in Chrome does not show correct format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5, cross-browser

Just start doing MVC. Following the example in this page： [Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation) in this [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) tutorial.

In the model, there is a date and format as:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The date format is according to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634470/3454439). So (using Chorme, Edge and IE) when I in the i) Index page, ii) Details page, or even in the iii) Delete page, I see the date displayed as yyyy-MM-dd (e.g. 1959-04-15 for April 15 in 1959).

But when I go to Edit page, the date is different for different browser.

Chrome: 04/15/1959
Edge: 4/15/1959
IE: 1959-04-15

(When I view source in all 3 browsers, all show 1959-04-15.)

I think the following suggestion (according to [the tutorial's description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) is causing the trouble, but even I remove the following culture specification, the result for all browsers are same.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture ="en-US" />
    <!--elements removed for clarity-->
</system.web>
```

1. The regional setting in my computer is 'English (Hong Kong SAR)'. Short date is format as d/M/yyyy.
2. Also when i view data in the Local DB, the date shown is '15/4/1959 0:00:00'. Looks like it uses the computer's regional setting.

Can anyone explain why the date is different in Edit mode? Also how to fix for Chrome?  I know someone has suggested other methods (like adding a model, file, etc), but I just want to see if there is an easy solution without adding additional file/model. Thanks.

Comment: IE does not support `<input type="date"` (also I assume you have a typo in the question - missing a `y` in `DataFormatString = "{0:yyy-MM-dd}"`)

Comment: Note also `<globalization culture ="en-US" />` (server side culture) has nothing to do with the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (which renders the date in the clients culture)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, that is a typo. Missing a 'y'. Now add back. Thanks.

Comment: After some research, here are what I find useful: i) For datetime property in model, do not go to the trouble and mark it as `DataType.Date`. ii) As @StephenMuecke has pointed out, it is better to use jQuery UI datepicker. (re: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/how-to-add-jquery-datepicker-in-mvc/) iii) Better format all date as yyyy-mm-dd. Same for formatting in datepicker by jQuery UI.

Comment: This page https://html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php gives some background information about HTML date picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[DataType(DataType.Date)]` generates the `type="date"` attribute when using `@Html.EditorFor()` which in turn generates the browsers HTML-5 datepicker. `type="date"` is not supported in IE, which is why you get a textbox only with the date displayed in the specified format.

For a comparison of HTML-5 support across various browsers, refer [HTML 5 TEST](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-68/edge-18/firefox-60/ie-11.html). Note also that FireFox has only just started supporting `type="date"`.

As for the date being displayed in `yyyy-MM-dd` format in your `Index` and `Details` views, that would be because you are using `@Html.DisplayFor()` which uses the `DataFormatString` property of `[DisplayFormat]` to format the value.

On option in your `Index` and `Details` views is to just use

```
@Model.YourDate.ToString("d") // or what ever format string you want
```

Another alternative is to change the attribute to

```
DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

so that `@Html.DisplayFor()` generates the correct format, and then in the `Edit` view, use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YourDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date" })
```

to generate the browsers HTML-5 datepicker.

But if you want a consistent datepicker across all browsers, then you need to use a jQuery plugin (for example [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)).

Note also that the culture on the server has nothing to do with the browsers HTML-5 datepicker, which renders the date in the browsers culture.

Comment: 1) If I use `{0:d}` in DataFormatString, all pages but Edit are ok. (That is, I see d/M/yyyy - good for my regional setting). However, in the Edit mode, in Chrome, I get a string as 'mm/dd/yyyy'. Click on it will have a datepicker for the current date! But I need to have the date for the record (i.e. 15/4/1959) right in the edit box. 2) In the Edit view, should the `EditorFor()` be used?

Comment: No, you need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YourDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date" })` as per my answer

Comment: Sorry. Still shows up as '04/15/1959'. It is not even close to my regional setting. Looks like US regional setting? (I don't have `globalization` statement in my web.config.)

Comment: I assume you have not understood my answer. The whole purpose of the HTML-5 datepicker is to display the date in the **browsers** culture. I I open you site I would see dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. If a user in the US opened it, they would see it in `MM/dd/yyyy` format (which is why you need to pass the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format). What is displayed has nothing to do with what is on your server (its client side code)

Comment: So again. If you want control of the format, and if you want it supported in all browsers, then use a jQuery plugin as I noted

Comment: I am doing all these in my machine! So the server and the client are in the same machine! Short date format for my machine is : d/M/yyyy. Say if I do not want any datepicker now (or will use the datepicker in jQuery), I just want the date displayed in Edit mode is same as others in Index/Details/Delete page. Now they are not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173200/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user3454439).