# How to set value of default date in DateTime EditorFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have tried different approach to make a dateTime text box, this is the one that works, but the problem is I cannot set a default date.

Here's what I am working on:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Then I set the date today, `DateTime.Now` like this `model.NotifyDate = DateTime.Now;`
[image]

It doesn't set the date. However, if I remove `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` from the model I will get:
[image]

I will get the date, but the calendar is gone. What's the problem? Or am I using the `datepicker` wrong?

Here's my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NotifyDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track! Defaults such as this should be set in the `ViewModel`
(as it appears you're doing w/ `model.NotifyDate = DateTime.Now;`)

The problem here appears to be that the browser is expecting the value for the generated html `input` element to be formatted differently -- namely, `yyyy-MM-dd` vs `yyyy/MM/dd`.
(note the use of **`-`** vs **`/`**)

In order for the browser to correctly display the date, the value must be formatted as `2019-09-23`.

ex:

```cs
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634470/12093051) is a great answer to a similar question that should shed some more light on what's going on as well.

Comment: Still the same problem. If I remove `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` it can be set, but the calendar will not appear.

Comment: @AdorableVB right, if you remove `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` the generated html `input` element will have `type=datetime` - which isn't supported - so the browser won't know to show the datepicker.  
I've edited my answer to include a link to another SO question/answer that should shed some additional light on what's going on.

Comment: I don't know how it worked today, pretty sure I was doing the same yesterday, but `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` did the trick. I guess browsers only accept that format, what I'm bothered is that on display its still `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Since Browser is expecting the value for the generated HTML input, you either need to provide value with client-side javascript (or client-side datepicker) or bind the value to model.

You can bind the value to model and pass to view from the controller as follows.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
    var dateInfo = new DateInfo()
            {
                StartDate = DateTime.Now
            };
    return View(dateInfo);
}
```

Or you can assign value from client side. jQuery UI is simple and easy to implement. You can [Visit](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) .

Answer (score 1):

You should try this datepicker in js.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            weekStart: 1,
            clearBtn: true,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            language: "tr",
            startDate: new Date(),
            autoclose: true
        });
```