# ASP.NET MVC @Html.EditorFor not displaying DateTime? value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class called depositLog and in depositLog I have this defined:

```
public DateTime? ChqDate { get; set; }
```

and the value I getting from the database call is this:

```
ChqDate = {2020-10-01 12:00:00 AM}
```

I am trying to display this value in my view using `@Html.EditorFor` like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChqDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" } })
```

But it displays this instead:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

How do I get it to display the date instead?

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634470/11683?

Comment: Can you try with a textbox instead; @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ChqDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control",@type = "date"})

Comment: Yup that works....if you put that into an answer I can accept it.